# What does "this"-keyword do in this foreach-loop?

Tags: c#, pointers, foreach, this

What exactly does the "this"-thing do and point towards in this code?
Is it possible to write the foreach-loop without the keyword "this"?

```
public class Member : IUser {

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}


public class MemberList : List<Member> {
    public MemberList StartsWith(string str) {
        var result = new MemberList();
        foreach (var m in **this**) {

            if (m.Username.StartsWith(str)) {
                result.Add(m);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: It works because MemberList ("this") inherits from List.  Look [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list) for more details/examples.  See also [GetEnumerator](http://www.dotnetperls.com/getenumerator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will invoke the current classes `GetEnumerator` method.  Since your class inherits from `List<Member>`, it will use that list's enumerator for the `foreach` loop.

The `this` keyword reference to the current instance of the class, useful when you have methods that need to refer to itself.

You can read more about `this` on the [this (C# Reference) page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, so is it possible to write the foreach-loop without using the this-keyword?

Comment: You could invoke `GetEnumerator()` yourself, but that entire class is suspect based on what you've shown.